# How should I be creating a variable that depends on another in Swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method I'm using for my `UICollectionView`. The reuse identifier depends on the indexPath, so I was planning to do something like:

```
var reuseIdentifier: String

if indexPath.row == 0 {
    reuseIdentifier = "One"
} else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    reuseIdentifier = "Two"
} else if indexPath.row == 2 {
    reuseIdentifier = "Three"
}

var cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, indexPath:indexPath)
```

Is this correct? Should `reuseIdentifier` be an optional String, or is it fine being a normal one?

Furthermore, am I handling it correctly in the `nil` case? If it's other than 2, `reuseIdentifier` is *nothing*, right? (Which is different from nil?) I should be handling this distinctly, right?

Answer (score 1):

Why not something simpler, like this?

```
let reuseIdentifier = ["One", "Two", "Three"][indexPath.row]
```

**Note:** this will crash if `indexPath.row > 2`. If this might happen, then you should be more careful. You might consider something like this:

```
extension Array {
    func at(index: Int) -> T? {
        if index >= count {
            return nil
        } else {
            return self[index]
        }
    }
}

// ...

let reuseIdentifier: String? = ["One", "Two", "Three"].at(indexPath.row) // might be nil
```

Comment: That... is really cool. What if I had a more complicated structure, though, and I couldn't do it in one line? Are constants so limited in that they need to be initialized on the same line that they're declared?

Comment: @DougSmith Well, you can definitely use `var` if you want to, but constants are often safer and clearer. (The Swift guide says, "If a stored value in your code is not going to change, always declare it as a constant with the let keyword. Use variables only for storing values that need to be able to change.") If you have more complicated logic, perhaps it could be encapsulated in a helper function?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a `var` of non-optional type and never assign to it, it's a compile time error.

If you want to let it be nil, you'll need to declare it as an optional. Then you'll need to appropriately handle the case where it is nil -- since the table will accept a nil cell, you could do that.

Comment: So in this case it should be optional, as in rare situations it may not get set? Which would then make it nil? What happens if I pass a nil String object as an argument?